How to write a formula returning from specific
I am working on a Google Sheet. Here I have a somewhat non standard table. To cut it short, I was able to designate "1" in column A for each row that fulfills my requirement.
Imagine that the "1" is spread in column A in the following cells:
A7 /
A9 / 
A11 / 
A12 /  
A14 /
A15 /
A16 /
A19 /
A21 /

and so on...
what I would like to have a formula is that in column B it will return:
b7=1 /
B9=2 /
b11 AND B12=3 /
B14, 15, 16=4 /
B19=5

the idea is that on each row with a single text value assigned, it will return 1, blank columns will return blank and succeeding consecutive rows with values will be counted as the same next number, if i am making any sense

Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. Please [edit] your question and insert a table of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a blank sheet maker that lets you share safely.

Assuming that you have put the number 1 in several rows of column A2:A, put this formula in row 2 of a free column:
=let( 
  data, A2:A, 
  ordinals, scan(0, data, lambda(a, c, 
    if(c = 1, a + (offset(c, -1, 0) <> 1), a) 
  )), 
  map(data, ordinals, lambda(d, o, 
    if(d, o, iferror(ø)) 
  )) 
)

See
let(),
scan(),
offset()
and
map().
